# In what order should I watch Daily Lives of High School Boys series?

Tags: daily-lives-of-high-school-boys

According to Wikipedia, there are 12 main episodes and 7 specials. In the beginning of the second main episode, there is a note saying: "this story has a proper ending". I guess this is supposed to mean the story continues (or is concluded) in a special episode. So what is the proper order of the series?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"This story has a proper ending"

**Sarcasm**

It's more or less a running-gag of the show that it has no real ending.

> Actually, the ending repeats the first scene of the anime, where the three friends go to school again (just weirder), although their school-time (and story) should be over.

I think you should watch the 12 normal episodes and then the specials. I can't remember them, however, but the main anime works without them.